# How can I check value and key of collection in one line?

Tags: php, laravel

How can I check value of [Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb1rG.png) in one line?
For example: `auth()->user()->roles->findKeyWithValue('title' => 'Admin')`
I need for Middleware, like: `if (auth()->user()->roles->existInCollection(['title' => 'Admin'])`

[Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb1rG.png)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to retrieve a collection if all you're doing is checking for existence of a single record.

```php
if (auth()->user()->roles()->where("title", "admin")->exists()) {
    ...
}
```

This will query the database only for whether or not the given record exists. What you are attempting to do with a collection is fetching all the fields of every entry from the database, and then doing a `foreach` loop to check every item and see if it matches.

For something as small as a list of user roles, going through that process won't be very hard on your response times and server resources. But it's good practice to avoid retrieving needless datasets when possible.

Comment: My answer was based exclusively on the initial request without looking further. I have upvoted your answer since it is true that it is necessary to optimize the queries as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the role exists using `contains`:

```php
if (auth()->user()->roles->contains('title', 'Admin')) {
 // true
}
```

Doc: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-contains

Comment: You’re welcome! Note: you can avoid the = if you want.